# Changing the colors of the specific dots in scatterplot vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors, scatter

I would like to change the color of dots in top left part of the scatterplot.
I wrote a macro, no errors occurred but the color did not change :/

```
Sub Kolorowanie()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
a = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
b = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)

If a(i) < 0 And b(i) > 0 Then
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
   With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Solid
   End With

Else
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas why it does not work?

Answer (score 9):

Get rid of the `.Solid` or put this **before** you set the `Forecolor.RGB`, I think that is overriding something (I have noticed this and some other bugs/inabilities to perform certain actions even as the Macro Recorder would make it seem these methods should work properly).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Kolorowanie()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim pt As Point

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

For Each pt In srs.Points
    With pt.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        '.Solid  'I commented this out, but you can un-comment and it should still work
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    End With
Next


End Sub
```

Or:

```
For Each pt In srs.Points
With pt.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Solid  'This is the default so including it doesn't do anything, but it should work either way.
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With
Next
```

Applying this to your code gives us:

```
Sub Kolorowanie()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
a = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
b = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)

If a(i) < 0 And b(i) > 0 Then
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
   With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Solid
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

   End With

Else
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Great -- glad it works. please consider "accepting" the answer if it's solved your problem. Cheers!