# Change Color on Colors on Pie Chart Based on Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

Hi just getting started with VBA excel - is there a way to color segments of a pie chart based on a value that does not directly feed into the Pie Chart?
My sample data would look like this :

```
        Steps   % Complete    Status
        Step1         100%          B  (Blue)
        Step2         50%           R  (Red)
        Step3         30%           G  (Green)
        Step4         15%           A  (Yellow)
```

The Pie Chart will be generated only using the first two columns (Steps and % Complete). But I want each of the segments for the pie chart to be colored based on the Status column.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194105/how-can-i-color-dots-in-a-xy-scatterplot-according-to-column-value/17195673#17195673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set in conditional formatting with vba to color each of the chart input cells (% Complete Column) according to the color represented by the Status Column (if Status "R" then %Complete color Red) - sample below
** Note - regular conditional formatting will not work

```
Dim status_value As Range
Set status_value = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(20, 3) - 
    If mycell.Value = "B" Then
        mycell2.Interior.color = RGB(0, 112, 192) 'Blue
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "R" Then
        mycell2.Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "A" Then
        mycell2.Interior.color = RGB(255, 192, 0) 'Amber
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "G" Then
        mycell2.Interior.color = RGB(0, 176, 80) ' Green
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "NA" Then
        mycell2.Interior.color = RGB(166, 166, 166) 'Grey
    End If
```

The below code will color the chart according to the interior color of the cells providing the values for the chart

```
Sub ColorCharts()
        For Each ch In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            For Each ser In ch.Chart.SeriesCollection
            s = Split(ser.Formula, ",")
                For i = 1 To UBound(ser.Values)
                    ser.Points(i).Interior.color = Range(s(2)).Cells(i).Interior.color
                Next i
            Next ser
        Next ch
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for ColorCharts()!