# Getting the wrong color for data points after I color dots in a xy scatterplot according to column value?

Tags: excel, vba, rgb, scatter

I've worked on my code basis this question that was answered: [How can I color dots in a xy scatterplot according to column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194105/how-can-i-color-dots-in-a-xy-scatterplot-according-to-column-value)

However, after I colour them by case, the colors that I have obtained are not entire accurate.

EDIT: I think I've found the problem. I have slicers to filter my scatter chart on Sheet 1, where the data is on Sheet 3.

E.g., the first 6 data points on my unfiltered data are "B / L / B / L / B", and the corresponding "Blue / Green / Blue / Green / Blue". However after I've applied for filters to only show for "L" which should only show Green, the first 6 data points are still showing "Blue / Green / Blue / Green / Blue". How should I go around this?

```
Sub ColorScatterPoints()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim srs_end As Long
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim p As Long
    Dim Vals$, lTrim#, rTrim#
    Dim valRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim myColor As Long

    Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Speed/Cons Chart").Chart
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection("with Full/Eco")

   '## Get the series Y-Values range address:
    lTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",", InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",") - 1, vbBinaryCompare) + 1
    rTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",")
    Vals = Mid(srs.Formula, lTrim, rTrim - lTrim)
    Set valRange = Range(Vals)  '#Column G / 7


    srs_end = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    
    For p = 1 To srs_end
        Set pt = srs.Points(p)
        Set cl = valRange(p).Offset(0, -5) '## color is 5 columns to the left.

        With pt.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            Select Case cl
                Case "L"
                    myColor = RGB(112, 173, 71) 'should appear as Green
                Case "B"
                    myColor = RGB(68, 114, 196) 'should appear as Blue
            End Select

            .ForeColor.RGB = myColor

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

After running the code, I noticed some of my data points labelled "L" are also in Blue. Vice-versa for my data points labelled "B".

Can someone show me where I got the code wrong?

Comment: I would look to separate the data into two data sets, then color code each set.

Comment: You need to debug and figure out where the problem is.  Try adding something like `Debug.Print p, cl.Address, cl.Value, myColor` just before the `End With`. And add a `Case Else` to deal with values which are not L or B

Comment: @TimWilliams I've tried them and it all appears normal, but still unsure of where the problem might lie.

Comment: Ok I think I've found the problem. I have slicers to filter my scatter chart on Sheet 1, where the data is on Sheet 3. The first 6 data points on my unfiltered data are "B / L / B / L / B", and the corresponding "Blue / Green / Blue / Green / Blue". However after I've applied for filters to only show for "L" which should only show Green, they are still showing "B/L/B/L/B" for the first 6 data points. How should I go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have rows which could be filtered out then you need to loop the input range and not the series points:

```vb
Sub ColorScatterPoints()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Series
    Dim valRange As Range, c As Range, i As Long
    Dim myColor As Long

    Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects("Speed/Cons Chart").Chart
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection("with Full/Eco")

   '## Get the series Y-Values range:
    Set valRange = Range(Split(srs.Formula, ",")(2))  '#Column G / 7

    'loop over the series Y-value range
    For Each c In valRange.Cells
        If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden Then 'check row is not filtered out
            i = i + 1                  'increment datapoint index
            Select Case c.Offset(0, -5).Value
                Case "L": myColor = RGB(112, 173, 71)
                Case "B": myColor = RGB(68, 114, 196)
                Case Else: myColor = RGB(150, 150, 150) '<< add a default
            End Select
            With srs.Points(i).Format.Fill 'format the i'th point
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = myColor
            End With
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! but i got stuck running the code at this part 
`With srs.Points(i).Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = myColor
 End With`

Comment: "I got stuck" doesn't tell us much that's useful in finding the problem.  What exactly happened?  Did you get an error?  If Yes what was it?

Comment: There wasn't an error, but the macro function [running] for a long time, resulting in developer (Not Responding). Have to kill off excel via task manager after 10 mins or so because it wasn't working. When I left the part of the code above out, it could run smoothly.

Comment: Sorry it's difficult for me to mimic your exact setup for testing - code above worked for me  but my chart and data might have been configured differently from yours.  Are you able to share your data/chart?

Comment: Hi William. I've discovered the reason why. For my series data `Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection("with Full/Eco")`, I have chosen rows G2:1048576 in order to minimise any manipulation the user has to do when the data table is updated (via Power Query). This caused the query to take forever to run and (Not Responding). Works now, thanks!