# Non-numerical XY-plot

Tags: excel, diagram

I have [the following table](https://gyazo.com/285d69f8c8933d1c3aa257a426e5d279). Now, what I want to do create an XY-plot of each risk ID against X-axis = ProjectPhase (a risk can either be in phase 1 thru 4 and they're non-numerical) with Y-axis = Risk Factor (numerical). I want to color each risk based on its theme. Is this even possible?

I tried messing around the PivotCharts, but without any luck. I was able to get the X-axis right, but I couldn't figure out how to make Risk Factor = Y-axis.

What's the most efficient way of achieving a chart that I am describing?

I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like you'd have to use VB code as in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981802/changing-the-colors-of-the-specific-dots-in-scatterplot-vba-excel/15982217#15982217

Answer (score 0):

If your Phases really are named Phase 1 ... Phase *n* then you could simply drop the word "Phase" from the phase names and move it to the axis title.

[image: XY Scatter]

The theme colours would need to be applied manually to each data point, if feasible (not sure how large your true data set is); otherwise, @Sam Hall is probably correct, that you need to handle this through VBA.